# Typescript: Declare function that takes parameter of exact interface type, and not one of its derived types

Tags: validation, typescript, inheritance, interface

```
interface I {
    a: number;
}

interface II extends I {
    b: number;
}

function f(arg: I) : void {
    // do something with arg without trimming the extra properties (logical error)
    console.log(arg);
}

const obj: II = { a:4, b:3 };
f(obj);
```

What I want to do is to make function `f` to accept only objects of type `I` and not type `II` or any other derived interface

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to do that, but the only way I can see is to make separate interface instead of extended one.

Comment: @kamyl even then because of the way typescript uses structural compatibility to determine type compatibility, it is impossible to guarantee the object passed will only have the type of the interface and only the fields specified on the interface

Comment: if you are using ts > 3.1 then it should be possible now, check this out: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-match-the-exact-object-shape/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in Typescript, in general, in most languages you cannot make such a constraint. One principle of object oriented programming is that you can pass a derived class where a base class is expected. You can perform a runtime check and if you find members that you don't expect, you can throw an error. But the compiler will not help you achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult because of the way typescript works. What you can do is add a `type` field to the base, which a derived interface would override. Then to limit a function to only accept the base explicitly:

```
interface IFoo<T extends string = "foo"> {
  type: T;
}

interface IBar extends IFoo<"bar"> {
}

function ray(baseOnly: IFoo<"foo">) {
}

let foo: IFoo = { type: "foo" };
let bar: IBar = { type: "bar" };

ray(foo); // OK!
ray(bar); // error
```

and the output error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'IBar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFoo<"foo">'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type '"bar"' is not assignable to type '"foo"'.
```

Comment: But you could still write `let other :{ type: "foo", other: number} = { type: "foo", other: 10};
  ray(other);` which is what I think he is trying to avoid. The problem is that the derived interfaces have to play along to achieve this, it is very easy to circumvent

Comment: I'm not sure I agree: while `let other = {type: "foo"}`, is a _different_ type, it does match the interface `IFoo<"foo">`. You wouldn't be able to pass `other` to a method expecting `IBar`. Equally, `let other = {type:"bar"}` is not assignable to anything expecting  `IFoo<"foo">`

Comment: But the problem he is trying to solve is that he doesn't want the caller of `ray` to pass I anything but an `IFoo`. You can easily pass something that is not an `IFoo` and even derived interfaces that do not willfully restrict themselves can be passed in so `interface IGoo extends IFoo<"foo"> {}` would be a valid parameter to `ray`. All derived interfaces must play along to achieve the effect.

Comment: Yes, you're right every interface _has_ to play along and not abuse it by doing `IGoo extends IFoo<"foo">`. You could possibly disallow T being "foo" when conditional types land though... but those are probably a way off.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (on ts 3.3 anyway):

```
// Checks that B is a subset of A (no extra properties)
type Subset<A extends {}, B extends {}> = {
   [P in keyof B]: P extends keyof A ? (B[P] extends A[P] | undefined ? A[P] : never) : never;
}

// Type for function arguments
type Strict<A extends {}, B extends {}> = Subset<A, B> & Subset<B, A>;
// E.g.
type BaseOptions = { a: string, b: number }
const strict = <T extends Strict<BaseOptions, T>>(options: T) => { }
strict({ a: "hi", b: 4 })        //Fine
strict({ a: 5, b: 4 })           //Error
strict({ a: "o", b: "hello" })   //Error
strict({ a: "o" })               //Error
strict({ b: 4 })                 //Error
strict({ a: "o", b: 4, c: 5 })   //Error

// Type for variable declarations
type Exact<A extends {}> = Subset<A, A>;
// E.g.
const options0: Exact<BaseOptions> = { a: "hi", b: 4 }        //Fine
const options1: Exact<BaseOptions> = { a: 5, b: 4 }           //Error
const options2: Exact<BaseOptions> = { a: "o", b: "hello" }   //Error
const options3: Exact<BaseOptions> = { a: "o" }               //Error
const options4: Exact<BaseOptions> = { b: 4 }                 //Error
const options5: Exact<BaseOptions> = { a: "o", b: 4, c: 5 }   //Error

// Beware of using Exact for arguments:
// For inline arguments it seems to work correctly:
exact({ a: "o", b: 4, c: 5 })   //Error
strict({ a: "o", b: 4, c: 5 })   //Error
// But it doesn't work for arguments coming from variables:
const options6 = { a: "o", b: 4, c: 5 }
exact(options6) // Fine -- Should be error
strict(options6)  //Error -- Is correctly error
```

You can see more detail in my comment [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-462134690).

So applied to your example:

```
interface I { a: number; }

interface II extends I { b: number; }

function f<T extends Strict<I, T>>(arg: T): void {
   // do something with arg without trimming the extra properties (logical error)
   console.log(arg);
}
const obj1: I = { a: 4 };
const obj2: II = { a: 4, b: 3 };
f(obj1); // Fine
f(obj2); // Error
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your `strict()` is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to give up on interfaces and use classes with private properties and private constructors.  These discourage extension:

```
export class I {
  private clazz: 'I'; // private field
  private constructor(public a: number) { 
    Object.seal(this); // if you really don't want extra properties at runtime
  }
  public static make(a: number): I {
    return new I(a); // can only call new inside the class
  }
}

let i = I.make(3);
f(i); // okay
```

You can't create an `I` as an object literal:

```
i = { a: 2 }; // error, isn't an I
f({a: 2}); // error, isn't an I
```

You can't subclass it:

```
class II extends I { // error, I has a private constructor
  b: number;
}
```

You *can* extend it via interface:

```
interface III extends I {
  b: number;
}
declare let iii: III;
```

and you *can* call the function on the extended interface

```
f(iii);
```

but you still *can't* create one with an object literal

```
iii = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // error
```

or with destructuring (which creates a new object also),

```
iii = { ...I.make(1), b: 2 };
```

, so this is at least somewhat safer than using interfaces.

---

There are ways around this for crafty developers.  You can get TypeScript to make a subclass via `Object.assign()`, but if you use `Object.seal()` in the constructor of `I` you can at least get an error at runtime:

```
iii = Object.assign(i, { b: 17 }); // no error at compile time, error at runtime
```

And you can always silence the type system with `any`, (although again, you can use an `instanceof` guard inside `f()` to cause an error at runtime).

```
iii = { a: 1, b: 2 } as any; // no error
f(iii); // no error at compile time, maybe error if f() uses instanceof
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!